# French users ??

Tags: discussion

For french user: 
How many french users use this GIS community?

Comment: more a community wiki question.

Comment: I removed the words "community wiki" from the question as I believe of the intent of the question is: *"How many french speakers are there here in GIS.se?"*, with community wiki being the type of Q being asked.

Comment: As noted in [Handling questions from non-english writers
](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228/handling-questions-from-non-english-writers), questions and answers here are english only, however people are welcome to create a language specific chat room (http://chat.stackexchange.com/) if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm here too, as an admin on ForumSIG.org and user of georezo.net. But i wonder if i understand your question : what survey should be available ?

Comment: For example, How many users use ArcGis or Api for webmapping ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a georezo and a forumsig member but I don't participate that much. When I need a specific information, in general google send me to the best source.

For my part, I use Qgis, OrbisGis and Mapinfo. I do work on webmapping essentially with openlayers (and mapserver) for now

(As Laurent, I don't really understand what you want. You're not precise)